# How to get the right pointer "alignment" in case of multiple inheritance in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, multiple-inheritance, void-pointers, vtable

Say I have two interfaces `IFoo`, and `IBar`; plus a concrete type `FooBar` implementing these interfaces:

```
class FooBar : public IFoo, public IBar
{
    //FooBar stuff
};
```

Somewhere I get a `void*` pointer, pointing on a `FooBar` instance.

```
void* fooBar = getOrCreateStuff();
```

Now I want to get a pointer on `IBar` from my `fooBar` instance.

```
IBar* iBar = static_cast< IBar* >(fooBar);
```

Unfortunately, `iBar` is not pointing on the right memory address. The example is silly on purpose -- in the real life, I don't know the concrete type I am pointing to.

**EDIT**: I am writing an API where I expose `template <class StuffT> StuffT getOrCreateStuff()` method. At this point, there is absolutely no way to know what type devs are using. The above example is showing you guys the way this method is supposed to be used. We register a concrete type in the API and get it back as an interface. It works like a charm when dealing with single inheritance, but multiple-inheritance is more complicated.

Any idea to get my iBar pointing on the working address offset?

Comment: Give both interfaces some virtual function (probably a pure virtual destructor) so they both have v-tables, then use `dynamic_cast<>` instead of `static_cast<>`.

Comment: why do you say :  "iBar is not pointing on the right memory address." ? ecause of the offset ? do you want ibar = foobar + (sizeof(IFoo) bytes) ?

Comment: @ildjarn, they already have virtual functions. Besides, `dynamic_cast` is useless against `void` pointers.

Comment: @misterwhy : That only begs the question -- why use `void*`?

Comment: I think the answer is "don't use `void*` in C++".

Comment: Shouldn't you first cast from `void *` to `FooBar *` and THEN to `IBar *`? Your `fooBar` points to beginning of memory block occupied by `FooBar` object, which is `IFoo` (if there is no vptr). Compiler does not know that it has to treat `void * fooBar` pointer as `FooBar *` before converting it to `IBar *`, you have to tell him that.

Comment: I don't think I have the choice. How would you instantiate unrelated types in a unified manner?

Comment: @misterwhy - I wouldn't have a function that returned two unrelated types like that. Return via a base, or from two separate functions or [erasure](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure.html).

Comment: @eharvest, you are absolutely right. But at the time I want my `IBar*`, I don't know the concrete type, so I don't know the offset (again, because I don't know that it is `sizeof (IFoo)`...)

Comment: maybe make one grand base interfase IBase and use it insted of void*?

Comment: @AzzA: I don't know the concrete type...

Comment: @misterwhy : If the unrelated types are finite and known at compile-time, then it sounds like a perfect use-case for a [static variant](http://www.boost.org/libs/variant/). Otherwise, possibly a candidate for a [dynamic variant](http://www.boost.org/libs/any/), but it still sounds like you have a serious design flaw.

Comment: @luskan: haha good idea, why isn't C++ providing object base class for all types by default huh? ;)

Comment: then it wouldnt be C++ but Java :)

Comment: if you dont know the type of fooBar, it's dead !

Comment: unless you use rtti... typeid

Comment: @ildjarn: Boost.Any doesn't spare you the cost of knowing your concrete type when the time comes. Of course, at compile time the unrelated types are finite but since I am providing an API and still not omniscient, I don't know the types developers will register in my API.

Comment: @eharvest: you're killing me. They're must be a way! rtti isn't helping much in this case.

Comment: @misterwhy If you don't know that `fooBar*` actually points to `FooBar` then why are you casting it to `IBar*` at all?

Comment: @mister why : rtti will not solve this. but, can't you change the code of getOrCreateStuff() to return the type in parameter ?

Comment: @AzzA : i think, he has a lot of FooBar classes that implement IBar...

Comment: @eharvest if all these `FooBar`'s have same signature (base list, "virtuality" and data size) then it does not matter to which `FooBar` to cast - they all have same layout in memory.

Comment: This is actually IoC polymorphic resolution that involves this issue. I can't find a way to workaround it.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know what you are pointing to you are out of luck! With static_cast(v) where "v" is of type "void*" you can only cast to the type "T*" if "v" resulted from an implicit conversion to "void*". If you really get a "void*" you'll need to first restore a type "B*" (e.g. some sort of base class; it doesn't have to be a common base class of all branches, just known to be present) which has at least one virtual function (e.g. its destructor if there isn't any functionality you want there) and from there you can use dynamic_cast(b) to restore some type somewhere in the inheritance hierarchy. Note that even this doesn't necessarily work if there are multiple "T" subobjects in the actual object.

The reason all this is necessary is that in an object using multiple inheritance the pointers to subobjects are getting adjusted: depending in which branch you are, the same subobject may exist and dealing with a specific one requires a different pointer. You can avoid the use of dynamic_cast(b) but only if you effectively create your own run-time information system.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I was actually looking for help. Maybe someone met the same problem in the past and solved it through a template based design trick.

Comment: The problem is that the run-time type of an object is, well, a run-time issue. You can't determine this at compile time. What you can do is to encapsulate the correct conversion to "void*" (i.e. first converting to a base suitable "B*" and then implicitly to "void*") and back (i.e. first static_cast<B*>(v) and then an appropriate dynamic_cast<T*>(b)).

Comment: @misterwhy - they have seen this problem in the past, that's what the [type erasure](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure.html) link I posted was about, but that's exactly what `boost::variant` and friends do.

Comment: @awoodland, type erasure doesn't apply here. We don't want to erase the type :)

Comment: @misterwhy - erasing the type is exactly what `void*` has done, just not terribly helpfully.

Comment: @awoodland: haha, touché! I'll change this later but for now it won't solve my problem.

Comment: @mister why : can you give examples of the types that can be returned by "getOrCreateStuff();" (if they were not casted to void*) ?

Answer (score 1):

Change `getOrCreateStuff()` to return something other than `void*`. If it returns `IStuff*`, and `FooBar` derives from `IStuff`, then you can use `dynamic_cast` to get to `IBar*`.

Comment: I don't know the concrete type that is returned.

Comment: My answer doesn't require knowing the concrete type. It only requires that the concrete type derives from IStuff.

Comment: My bad, you're right but that would be huge strain for devs since they would need to derive from a type I provide so they can use my API.

Comment: if the type derive from IBar, do directly : `iBar = (dynamic_cast<IBar*> getOrCreateStuff());`. but if does not derives from IBar* you could never cast it to IBar* .. and the result of the cast will be NULL so they dont use corrctly the api : you will be happy to return a great "error message". ironic here...

Comment: @eharvest: I'm not sure what you're getting at. You can't dynamic cast a `void*`.

Comment: the cast isin the case of `getOrCreateStuff()` returns anon-void pointer, aka a pointer to a derived class from `IBar`.

Comment: @eharvest: once more, there is no such `IBar` in real life. Types returned by `getOrCreateStuff()` will usually be unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure of :"Somewhere I get a void* pointer, **pointing on a FooBar instance**."

then, this is a solution :

```
IBar* iBar = static_cast<IBar*>(reinterpret_cast< FooBar* >(fooBar));
```

or :

```
IBar* iBar = dynamic_cast<IBar*>(reinterpret_cast< FooBar* >(fooBar));
```

as IBar is an interface, it must have a pure virtual method, so it is polymorphic, so dynamic cast an be used.

Comment: Nope, the example was silly on purpose. Again, `FooBar` is imaginary, I don't know the concrete types (plural) that can be returned.

Comment: @mister why : can you give examples of the types that can be returned by "getOrCreateStuff();" (if they were not casted to void*) ? getOrCreateStuff() returns void* ?

Comment: if the ... returns real object type and those objects inherit from IBar, the solution is :  do directly : iBar = (dynamic_cast<IBar*> getOrCreateStuff());. .. and if the result of the cast is NULL, the proramers dont use correctly the api : you will be happy to return a great "error message". ironic here...